# How to organize some Utils files in AngularJS to call from app.config?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I need to configure AngularJS - set default $http headers. In my case i need to generate some of them. To make this i need to call some reusable function from Utils service.

As app.config doesn't support services injection how can i organize my code to enable this injection?

```
app.service('Utils', function(){
    this.generateGuid(){}
});

app.config(['Utils', function(Utils){
    //...
}]);
```

Or should i create my own custom js files with raw functions?

Comment: Can you use `app.run` instead, or do you need stuff from your Utils service during the config phase?

Comment: By "reusable" you mean you need those function within the configuration phase as well as during runtime of the app?

Comment: i know i can use that, but i'm not sure this is ideologically correct. I'm configuring default headers for $http + request transformation function.

'reusable' - is a some aux function (e.g. generateGuid()), i can use in my controllers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Utils` service doesn't require any other services, you could write it as a provider like this:

```
app.provider('Utils', function () {
  this.generateGuid = function () {};

  this.$get = function () {
    return this; // a provider instance and service instance will be the same object.
  };
});
```

then inject a provider instance in app.config:

```
app.config(function (UtilsProvider) {
    UtilsProvider.generateGuid();
});
```

to use in app.run() or controllers, just inject a service instance as usual:

```
app.controller('FooController', function (Utils) {
    Utils.generateGuid();
});
```

Hope this helps.